# SQL - adding total by searching for another value relating to the amount

Tags: mysql, sql

been given this problem to solve
Write a function to get the payment sales figures from any given shop. The shop should be searched for by name.
 i have this so far

```
SELECT shopname SUM ( amount ) AS sales
FROM frs_Shop, frs_Payment
WHERE shopname = "shop name"
```

i have the amount to add up but when i go to compile it adds up every amount in this table

```
INSERT INTO frs_Payment
(payid, amount, paydatetime,            empnin,     custid, pstatusid, ptid) 

    values

    (101,   "3.99", "2015-10-26 16:26:15",  "NIN001",   1,  1,  1),
    (95,    "15.96",    "2015-09-24 16:26:15",  "NIN001",   1,  1,  1),
    (102,   "3.99", "2015-10-11 13:25:31",  "NIN003",   2,  1,  1),
    (11,    "11.97",    "2015-06-12 19:37:59",  "NIN010",   3,  1,  1),
    (7, "11.97",    "2015-04-11 12:41:28",  "NIN010",   3,  2,  4),
    (8, "7.98", "2015-05-05 22:49:02",  "NIN010",   3,  1,  1),
    (32,    "15.96",    "2015-07-19 02:26:49",  "NIN024",   5,  2,  4),
    (83,    "7.98", "2015-08-20 16:21:08",  "NIN011",   5,  2,  4),
    (6, "15.96",    "2015-03-04 10:51:03",  "NIN027",   6,  2,  4),
    (17,    "3.99", "2015-10-03 01:06:15",  "NIN028",   6,  1,  1),
    (39,    "11.97",    "2015-03-24 20:03:05",  "NIN027",   6,  1,  1),
    (103,   "3.99", "2015-10-27 14:45:11",  "NIN009",   7,  1,  1),
    (62,    "15.96",    "2015-10-12 14:23:23",  "NIN001",   8,  1,  1),
```

i want it to only add up the ones i specify with the empnin

Comment: Don't use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit, proper `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Are you filtering by empnin or shopname? Or both?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an explicit join, and a GROUP BY. I made an assumption on the primary/foreign key relationship between frs_Shop and frs_Payment.

```
SELECT s.shopname
       , p.empnin
       , SUM ( p.amount ) AS sales
FROM frs_Shop s
INNER JOIN frs_Payment p on s.empnin = p.empnin
WHERE s.shopname = "shop name"
GROUP BY s.shopname, p.empnin
```